# Issues parsing my json, I am getting this "JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, scrapy, html-escape-characters

```
my_json = '{"hello":"\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x3Cdiv\\x3E\\x20\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\HELLO"}'

json.loads(my_json)
```

I get this.

```
JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 11 (char 10)
```

What conversion do i need to use so my json will load?

Comment: Where does that JSON come from? Also, please provide the entire error message.

Comment: It's because of the backslashes in the string, you would have to double escape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just first convert python string into json and it will work for you.

```
my_json = json.dumps({
              "hello":"\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x3Cdiv\\x3E\\x20\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\HELLO"
                })
json.loads(my_json)
```

Comment: `{ "hello":"\x20\x20\x20\x3Cdiv\x3E\x20\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\HELLO" }` is **not** the same thing as OP's data, which is `'{"hello":"\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x3Cdiv\\x3E\\x20\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\HELLO"}'`. _just first convert python string into json and it will work for you._ That makes little sense, and it certainly isn't what the code you shared is doing.

Answer (score -2):

The suggestion of @pguardiario definitely is cleaner, but if you're just after the resulting `dict`, give [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) a try:

```py
In [77]: my_json                                                                
Out[77]: '{"hello":"\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x3Cdiv\\x3E\\x20\\x0A\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\HELLO"}'

In [78]: evaluated = eval(my_json)                                                          
Out[78]: {'hello': '   <div> \n    \\HELLO'}

In [79]: evaluated.items()                                                      
Out[79]: dict_items([('hello', '   <div> \n    \\HELLO')])
```

Comment: Please don't suggest using `eval`, some dev will find this and stick a security hole in their app without thinking about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: Why is eval a security hole?

Comment: Note that neither `eval` nor the safer `ast.literal_eval` is suitable to load actual JSON: the *Python* syntax handled by `eval` is subtly different from *JSON* syntax. Only very specific edge cases of the two overlap. `eval` should be avoided altogether since it offers no advantage whatsoever over `ast.literal_eval` but can execute *any and all arbitrary code* if the input is not sanitised.